# How to install osx sierra on virtualbox (on my mac)

Tags: macos, virtualbox, macos-sierra

I want to install on my macbook pro a second osx sierra.
I prefer to use virtualbox for this second osx.
The reason is that i will try to install composers, virtual hosts lavarel etc. and i dont want to harm my main osx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just followed these instructions, and they seem to have worked: [sierra-virtualbox-install.md](https://gist.github.com/arobb/447a962af4f07ef81e79987d686275e5).

You'll need the Install macOS Sierra.app from Apple, and you'll need to change the first step of the instructions to match it's name (remove "\ Public\ Beta").  I also had to format the virtual disk manually after booting with the install image.